# Java negative number doesn't come out positive

Tags: java

Need to get that negative number to iterate from -2345 to 2 3 4 5 then it sums to 14.  The part I can't figure out is the 2 3 4 5 comes out as -2 3 4 5...syntax I'm missing?? Maybe it is just a line of code or a for statement...

```
import java.util.*;
public class sumofNumbers{


static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);    

  public static void main(String[] args){

  int input;
  int sum = 0;
  int strnbr = 0;
  int counter = 1;
  String nbr = "";

    System.out.print("enter a number: ");
    input = console.nextInt();

    if (input == (-input)) {

        input = input * (-1);
        nbr = String.valueOf(input);
        strnbr = nbr.length();
        System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < strnbr; i++) {
            String var = nbr.substring(i, counter);
            int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
            System.out.print(var + " ");
            sum = sum + var1;
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);

    } else {
        nbr = String.valueOf(input);
        strnbr = nbr.length();
        System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < strnbr; i++) {
            String var = nbr.substring(i, counter);
            int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
            System.out.print(var + " ");
            sum = sum + var1;
            counter++;
        }
        System.err.println();
        System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
    }
```

}
}

Comment: How do you expect `if (input == (-input))` to be possible ?

Comment: Well `input` could be zero or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, technically.

Comment: I just noticed that...

Comment: why not just use Math.abs, then your logic would be the same

Comment: input in this case is -2345 and has to show as a negative number just like that as input but the spaced number has to remove the negative from the number.  It sums up positively so this isn't making sense to me.  When I remove the - from the input I get the right answer with spaces but the first number entered -2345 shows as 2345.

Comment: Math.abs doesn't work it has to look like this:                                                 enter a number: -2345
the digits of -2345 are: 2 3 4 5 
the sum is: 14   The sum has to add up to 14

Comment: I have fixed my answer with your requirements

Comment: The sum of the numbers between -2345 and 2345 is zero, not 14, and what `2 3 4 5` has to do with it remains obscure. Why you're converting the console input to an `int` and then back to a `String` and then back to its numeric value is another mystery. Are you trying to add the values, or the digits? Unclear what this is all about.

Comment: @EJP 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 14. Question is badly worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in your if statement:

```
if (input == (-input))
```

That will never be true.

This simplifies your code so it isn't duplicated twice based on a negative/positive number.  It could be done better, but I wanted to leave most of your code intact.

```
    System.out.print("enter a number: ");
    int input = console.nextInt();

    if (input < 0) {
        input = input * (-1);
    }

    String nbr = String.valueOf(input);
    int strnbr = nbr.length();
    System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strnbr; i++) {
        String var = nbr.substring(i, i + 1);
        int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
        System.out.print(var + " ");
        sum = sum + var1;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

Comments to your code:

- `if (input == (-input))` can only be true for `0` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, two fringe cases you probably don't care about. Looks like you meant `if (input < 0)`.
- `input = input * (-1)` is better written as `input = -input`.
- With the above, the `if` and the `else` blocks become the same, so you only need the `if` to do the `input = -input`.
  You can even do that without `if` by always doing `input = Math.abs(input)`.
- `counter` is unnecessary. You should use `substring(i, i + 1)` since that is what you really mean.
- `substring(i, i + 1).charAt(0)` is the slow way to write `charAt(i)`.
- To iterate all the characters of a String, you can call `toCharArray()` and use an enhanced `for` loop.
- In `print(var + " ")` it doesn't matter whether `var` is a `String` of one digit, a `char` with the digit, or an `int` with the digit. The result is the same.
- Since `nbr` will only contains the characters `'0'` to `'9'`, `Character.getNumericValue(ch)` is the slow way to say `ch - '0'`.
- `sum = sum + digit` can be shortened to `sum += digit`.
- Don't print to `System.err`.
- Java naming convensions state that class names should start with uppercase letter.
- Don't pre-declare your variables. Declare them where they are needed. This often also help reduce their scope.

Applying all of that, changes your code to:

```
public class SumOfNumbers {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("enter a number: ");
        int input = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");

        String nbr = String.valueOf(Math.abs(input));
        int sum = 0;
        for (char ch : nbr.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.print(ch + " ");
            sum += ch - '0';
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
enter a number: -2345
the digits of -2345 are: 2 3 4 5 
the sum is: 14
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your code starting with

```
if (input == (-input)) {
```

with

```
    System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");
    input = Math.abs (input);
    nbr = String.valueOf(input);
    strnbr = nbr.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < strnbr; i++) {
        String var = nbr.substring(i, counter);
        int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
        System.out.print(var + " ");
        sum = sum + var1;
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
```

and delete end brackets

Comment: Can't use the Math.abs(input) because both numbers come up as negative or positive....tried

Comment: I can not understand your comment

Comment: So where is Sum and Average in that setting up of the variables??

Comment: Sorry I thought you had some programming experience.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Missing `=` before `Math.abs()`. --- `nbr.substring(i, counter).charAt(0)` (shortened), is the same as `nbr.charAt(i)`. --- Don't use `System.err`.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing out the typo